# Ы после Ц в фамилиях

Tags: орфография

Помню, в школе мы учили, что Ы после Ц пишется не только в сакраментальном "цыган на цыпочках...", а еще и в фамилиях, типа Куницын, Лисицын и т.д. Но почему тогда, например, Ельцин и Вицин пишется через И?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что фамилии (иногда и имена и отчества)правилам не подчиняются.Как в церкви запишут при рождении (или потом в ЗАГСе), так и правильно. Значит, тот, кто первый раз писал эту фамилию, правил не знал,а теперь уже никто не поменяет.Поэтому и Ильичём,если касается Ленина, а если остальных - Ильичом.

Comment: А может, дело не только в ошибке? Честно говоря, я не знаю правила: в фамилиях пиши Ы. Есть другое: в корне И (кроме исключений), в суффиксах и окончаниях Ы. В фамилиях Куницын и Лисицын это как раз суффикс, причем легко выделяемый. В фамилии Вицин на сегодняшний день далеко не каждый увидит корень виц- (прут) и суффикс. Возможно, в этом и причина ошибки. Слово воспринимается как цельное, неразложимое.

Answer (score 1):

В русских фамилиях после ц пишется буква и или ы в соответствии с традицией и с регистрацией в официальных документах, напр.: Ципко, но Цыбин; Куницын, Курицын, Синицын, Скобельцын, Солженицын, но Ви***цин***, Ель***цин***, Ци***цин***. ( Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина).

Answer (score 0):

На фамилии это правило не распространяется, так что Вы можете встретить как Вицына, так Вицина (или какая-то похоже звучащая фамилия).